# How to make iptables logs to identify protocols by name and not by number?

Tags: iptables

In my iptables log files (Ubuntu 16-04), all messages from my LAN router and from other hosts in the LAN, related to IGMP have "PROTO=2". Is there a way to change this and get "PROTO=IGMP"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
sed -e "$(awk '/^[[:space:]]*(#|$)/ { next } ;
               { print "s/ PROTO="$2" / PROTO="$3" /;" }' \
          /etc/protocols)" /path/to/iptables.log
```

This uses `awk` to construct a `sed` script from fields 2 and 3 of the `/etc/protocols` file.  It then runs that `sed` script on `/path/to/iptables.log`.  This will convert **ALL** numbered protocols in the log file to their corresponding names.

If you prefer, you could save the output of the `awk` script to a file (e.g. called `verbose-proto.sed` and then run it with `sed -f` (or even edit it to add `#!/bin/sed -f` as the first line and `chmod` it to make it executable).  e.g.

```sh
$ awk '/^[[:space:]]*(#|$)/ { next } ;
     { print "s/ PROTO="$2" / PROTO="$3" /;" }' \
    /etc/protocols > ./verbose-proto.sed

$ printf "%s\n" 1 i '#!/bin/sed -f' . w | ed -s verbose-proto.sed
$ chmod +x ./verbose-proto.sed 
$ ./verbose-proto.sed /path/to/iptables.log
```

If all you want to do is change that one protocol number `2` to `IGMP`, it's much simpler:

```
sed -e 's/ PROTO=2 / PROTO=IGMP /' /path/to/iptables.log
```

(the `awk` script generates about 50 lines with regexp search and replace rules like this - one for each known protocol in `/etc/protocols`)

Comment: Magic! I was expecting some setting in iptables configuration that would achieve this.  It never crossed my mind writing a script that would look into /etc/protocols to dynamically construct and run a sed script able to do all substitutions. I had heard about awk, but this really shows its powers. Thank you for sharing this ingenious solution.

Comment: no problem, it made the question more interesting for me to answer than just the single 2-->IGMP solution :).  BTW, i think of it more as showing off the power of shell than `awk`.  The `awk` and `sed` scripts themselves are fairly simple examples of what those tools can do....it's the shell's ability to combine multiple tools with pipelines and command substitution that's really powerful.